# Повышение репутации за лайки на мете

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, репутация

Я неделю сижу на мете и заметил, что в большинстве хороших вопросов стоит много плюсов (голосов «за»). Но пользователем от этих плюсов ничего не даётся: ни наград, ни репутации... Почему так? Можно же начислять пользователю репутацию за плюсы, ну не как на SO, но хотя бы по 1 баллу.

Как вы считаете, нужно ли добавлять пользователям на мете репутацию за голоса в их вопросах/ответах?

Comment: [tag:статус-так-задумано]

Comment: @Grundy, это ты к чему?

Comment: про репутацию на метасайтах :)

Comment: @Grundy, так задумано? Но можно же изменить задумку

Comment: Неа, [Reputation of MSO will be reflected on SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250077/reputation-of-mso-will-be-reflected-on-so)

Comment: [Why is there no reputation on meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277274/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, фигово

Comment: Репутация на мете приведет к тому, что популистских предложений будет больше, а спорных - меньше. Кроме того если вдруг будет отдельная метарепутация, то многие предложения будут испытывать на себе куда более сильное влияние автора, чем содержания.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму полностью согласен! Отсутствие репутациии (отдельной) на мете позволяет безбоязненно писать о спорном и неприятном.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму при этом очень было бы неплохо [разрешить конкурсы на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4271/176217).

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Да, но при этом на главной мете есть репутация. И там прекрасно выдвигаются популисткие предложения, а спорные минусятся в пол. И там реально стремновато отклоняться от "линии партии".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Здорово, когда у инженера есть так называемые "soft skills" — умение и мотивация выступать перед публикой, писать различные обращения, призывы и инструкции, общаться, договариваться и т.п.

Но мы же не менеджеры по продажам, чтобы судить друг о друге по soft skills. Мы ценим прежде всего знания и способность решать задачи, что-то создавать с помощью hard skills. Поэтому репутация даётся только за проявление hard skills:

- за придумывание хороших вопросов,
- вдвойне — за написание хороших ответов (т.е. разработку хороших решений),
- понемногу за наведение порядка (подтверждённые правки и зелёные галочки),
- и изредка, но помногу — за выдающиеся знания и решения (награды за конкурсы).

Comment: ... для всего остального есть [meta.SE].

Comment: @alexolut ну она как раз для профессиональных обсуждателей. )

Answer (score 5):

Знаки на мете даются. И репутация по-тихому считается, просто она нигде не показывается.

Comment: Это я, почтальон Стековерфловкин! Принёс мета-репутацию! Только я вам её не отдам! Потому что у вас доку́ментов нету.

Comment: В частности, на Мете можно получать знаки за псевдо-репутацию: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard

Comment: @älёxölüt XDDDDD

Comment: @älёxölüt нету слова нету)